# Can I override the default "Drag and Drop" behaviour when dragging email item from outlook?

Tags: outlook, drag-and-drop, overriding

After dragging email item from outlook, my own application (written in C#) can get the data and retrieve the msg data when the email item is dropped on it. But is it possible to override the default "drag and drop" behavior so that I can send some information else (rather than the default information) when dragging an email item and pick up the information when the item is dropped on my own application?

Answer (score 1):

No - there might be some very ugly hacks, but no usable approach.

What you could do though is utilize something from the mail in information you receive via Drag'n'Drop as a unique identifier  somewhere in the mail information that gets transmitted.
With the ability to identify the mail in Outlook you could e.g. connect to Outlook via automation or use a minimal Outlook AddIn that can be queried for what you need.